# Selecting phone calls in where date is today

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve phone calls from our Avaya database in SQL 2012 and i can't seem to get the dates on my code right.

```
cmdCalls = String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCallList WHERE CreateDate > cast('" & DateYesterday & "' as date)")
```

This is my query string

```
Dim DateYesterday As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(<insert number of days>).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I can't seem to pull the data i need from the database, it does subtract the days from the date variable but the problem is its using the days as months on the query and it shows all the records from the month instead of day

The Dates formats on the database are '2017-06-08 12:04::00:000' for example

Comment: What is the database data type of the CreateDate column? If a temporal type like `datetime` rather than `char`/`varchar`, it is a binary structure and has no format.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but it might really just be date

Comment: It can't be a date since the value contains hours and minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current date in the database:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblCallList
WHERE CreateDate >= CAST(getdate() as date);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that is returning 0 results

Comment: @K.Chanel . . . You should edit the question and provide sample data.  In the meantime, try `cast(getdate() - 1 as date)` to see if you get anything from yesterday.

Comment: why not use proper dateadd? `where createDate >= cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date);

Comment: Both these answers still return 0, seems like it only ever subtracts to months

Comment: @GordonLinoff As for sample data well it just returns all calls from last month which are 4000 and greatly increases memory use

Comment: @K.Chanel . . . You need to look at the maximum `CreateDate` in the table to see how recently data has been inserted.

Comment: Seem to have found my problem... it stopped registering calls after 2017-05-28 ... looks like I need to talk to someone here about this, thank you